# Creating a folder based on email title and moving the email to the folder

Tags: vba, macos, outlook, applescript

I changed from Windows to MacOS.

I used VBA code to create a folder under the inbox based on email title and move the email to the folder.

I'm trying to do the same with AppleScript.

I would appreciate if someone can help me write the same logic in AppleScript (or suggest an alternative to somehow keep using the VBA code).

```
Public Function ReturnNonAlpha(ByVal sString As String) As String

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To Len(sString)
    If Mid(sString, i, 1) Like "[0-9]" Then
        ReturnNonAlpha = ReturnNonAlpha + Mid(sString, i, 1)
    End If
Next i

End Function


Function CheckForFolder(strFolder As String) As Boolean

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim FolderToCheck As Outlook.MAPIFolder 

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olInbox = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

On Error Resume Next
Set FolderToCheck = olInbox.Folders(strFolder)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not FolderToCheck Is Nothing Then
    CheckForFolder = True
End If 

ExitProc:
Set FolderToCheck = Nothing
Set olInbox = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

End Function


Function CreateSubFolder(strFolder As String) As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olInbox = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set CreateSubFolder = olInbox.Folders.Add(strFolder)

ExitProc:
Set olInbox = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

End Function


Function SearchAndMove(lookFor As String)

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim FolderToCheck As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim myItem As Object
Dim MyFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim lookIn As String
Dim newName As String
Dim location As Integer
Dim endLocation As Integer

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olInbox = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

For Each myItem In olInbox.Items

    lookIn = myItem.Subject

    If InStr(lookIn, lookFor) Then

        endLocation = InStr(lookIn, "SUP-")
        newName = ReturnNonAlpha(lookIn)
        newName = Mid(newName, 1, 5)

        If CheckForFolder(newName) = False Then
            Set MyFolder = CreateSubFolder(newName)
            myItem.Move MyFolder
        Else
            Set MyFolder = olInbox.Folders(newName)
            myItem.Move MyFolder
        End If

    End If

Next myItem

End Function


Sub myMacro(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim str As String

str = "[JIRA]"
SearchAndMove (str)

End Sub
```

Comment: You can probably employ someone on Airtasker.

Answer (score 0):

I was really determined to find a solution, so eventually with some help from https://hackernoon.com/automated-inbox-cleansing-with-outlook-2016-and-applescript-49cf4c4422fa

I was able to write a script which does what I need.
I thought I'll share it for future references since I don't see a lot of info about applescript around here.
This script basically creates a subfolder under inbox based on email subject and move the email there. I wrote it with my own problem to solve in mind, but you can do adjustments to your own problems.

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set myInbox to folder "Inbox" of default account
    set theMessages to messages 1 through 20 of inbox

    repeat with theMessage in theMessages
      try
        set theSubject to subject of theMessage

        if theSubject contains "[JIRA]" then

            set s to quoted form of theSubject
            do shell script "sed s/[a-zA-Z\\']//g <<< " & s
            set newFolderName to the result
            set numlist to {}
            repeat with i from 1 to count of words in newFolderName
                set this_item to word i of newFolderName
                try
                    set this_item to this_item as number
                    set the end of numlist to this_item
                end try
            end repeat
            set newFolderName to first item of numlist as text
            if mail folder newFolderName exists then
                move theMessage to mail folder newFolderName of myInbox
            else
                make new mail folder at myInbox with properties {name:newFolderName}
                move theMessage to mail folder newFolderName of myInbox
            end if
        end if

    on error errorMsg
        log "Error: " & errorMsg
    end try
end repeat
end tell
```